# Why the communication between the SQL database and the ORMs/Query Builders is done only by SQL concrete syntax?

Tags: sql, orm, abstract-syntax-tree, query-builder

As I know, all ORMs and Query Builders deal with the database by queries expressed in the SQL concrete syntax, in the same way as humans do when writing SQL queries from scratch.

The pitfall in that approach is that, without caution, approach might lead the final software or the related libraries to SQL injection issues, and another disadvantage is that sending and parsing textual content is more expensive than the same content serialized in a binary format.

Despite this, even after decades since those tools became popular, no alternative protocol emerged or popularized to enhance the communication between the SQL database server and that kind of client. Objectively: is there a technical reason for that or is just for historical reason?

Comment: It’s the translation layer between your application and database. A database that communicates in SQL, requires SQL as input. So your Java, Nodejs, or whatever application has to translate its commands to SQL. And SQL injection or code injection, both have similar security issues, it’s not something specific for SQL or databases

Comment: Yes, you are right. Code injection is not a SQL-specific problem. There are similar issues in other contexts using different (usually) textual languages, like template injection in HTML/JS. But using textual languages in general makes things harder to deal with because when using those languages, the escaping mechanisms are complex and those grammars are by definition human readable.